# Detect Input.GetMouseButtonUp outside a GameObject in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How do I detect Input.GetMouseButtonUp outside a specific GameObject's area in Unity? Are there any Unity Assets for this, or should we do this programmatically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It certainly has to be done by programming it, whether there is an asset or not. As it is rather easy to program, I doubt there is one.

What you need to understand is, that Input.GetMouseButtonUp(int button) is an event and entirely decoupled from any "position". The description from the API says "Returns true during the frame the user releases the given mouse button.".

So **in the frame** a mouse button has been released you want to check if the arrow is "touching" or laying over some GameObject (GO). According to your example you will do nothing when the GO was hit, and else do something.

One way to do that is to use the following method:
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html

Your GameObject will at least need a collider, maybe a rigidbody too in order to be detected by the ray. I'm not completely sure atm if both are needed.

Additional note: Having an UI element, this method could also be used to set some flag while hovering over it e.g. : http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseOver.html